# drupal q=vectorize-files means which php file?

Tags: uri

I started learning drupal today but I am unable to understand where https://www.artworkgeeks.com/vectorize-files is going. In htaccess file any url is getting pointed to index.php?q=$l but I dont understand which php file in which folder is getting executed. I know this is really basic but I m unable to find out answer online.

How to detect which template file and which php file is getting executed for particular url. Some other developer have removed all of the site theme control and module control options from admin panel. Now how to locate files.

Answer (score 4):

There is no specific "file" to find as paths don't need to map to files in Drupal. One registers a path in the system by implementing [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

```
hook_menu() {
  return array(
    'vectorize-files' => array(
      'page callback' => 'some_function',
    ),
  );
}
```

I would start by grepping or otherwise searching all the custom modules of the site for the string "vectorize-files", which is the path you are looking for. You should be able to find a `.module` file that defines this path.

Failing that, the path is registered, together with it's module name , in the `menu_router` table, where you can track down it's origin.

Comment: where this hook_menu function is written? Can you please tell me the filepath and folder?

Comment: @AyazAlavi Drupal has a menu registry system, it's not a one-path-per-file type of deal. You'll have to dig to find what you're looking for, no-one without access to the full code will be able to give you the answer. The best place to start would be in all files with the `.module` extension under "sites/all/modules".

Comment: I updated the answer to make more explicit some points, and incorporate @Clive's suggestion.

Comment: To add to what said by Letharion, in some cases the page callback is `drupal_get_form()`; in such cases, the function that builds the form is reported in "page arguments."